# How to use proxy in nginx to redirect a path to VM on same network

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am working on some improvements on a webapp for a client.
Actually there is only a production server (on a VM) where the webapp is hosted (running on Nginx).
My clients wants a new server so that they can test the new features before they are available in production.
They have already cloned the production VM to create the new dev one, and asked me to redirect a path of their website ([www.exemple.com/dev](http://www.exemple.com/dev)) to the dev webapp.
Both VM's are on the same network (I access them via 10.10.38.X IP address) but I do not know their public IP.
I am struggling with that for a moment now without managing to do this.
Here is the nginx config (prod server)

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
      
        server_name  _;
      
    root         /site/app;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;


    location /api/ {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, authorization' always;
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true' always;
        }

        location /dev {
                autoindex on;
                alias /dev_app;
        }

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
```

Currently the /dev path go to a folder where the dev webapp can be found (but there is only the front-end part, the dev server was created to also have a dev backend and database which are hosted in the same VM)

Comment: try with ```location /dev {
                proxy_pass http://<ip>/;
        }``` here IP is : 10.10.38.X ( through which you are accessing it )

Comment: You would also need to install the nginx in your dev server and map the incoming traffic to the respected port.

Comment: @sachin The dev server is actually a copy of prod server so I have same nginx conf for now. Using your method will not required any authetication, like in ssh ?

Comment: does your live server already contains ssh authentication ?

Comment: if yes, then your dev server also needs it

Comment: Yes it does, how can I add ssh authentication to proxy ?

Comment: Ok then first, lets do it witout SSH. if it works, then we can try adding SSH.

Comment: Glad that it worked. Did you change anything else ?

Comment: No nothing I just tried with other path (like /test) to be sure it was not render by the cache from the old dev version